# join between three tables

Tags: mysql, sql, join

How to do join between 3 tables.
I have 3 tables called

The relation between Equipment and Instructor is `many to many`.
through the intermediate table EquipInstruct.

```
Equipment (E-id)
Instructor (I-Id)
EquipInstruct (E-id I-id)
```

How can I join the three tables?

> It will be greatly appreciated if some help me craft the query for that.

Comment: depends on what you want to do.  i would do EquipInstruct ei left join Equipment e on ei.E-id = e.E-id left join Instructor i on ei.I-id = i.i-id.  but we need a litle more information on the data structure and what kind of outputs you're trying to produce.

Comment: What result do you want?  What are you trying to do?  Do you have some example data?

Comment: Have you actually looked _anywhere_ on how to do JOINs before asking this question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT *
FROM Equipment, Instructor, EquipInstruct
WHERE Equipment.id = EquipInstruct.Eid
AND Instructor.id = EquipInstruct.Iid
```

Or whatever you've called the ids.

Comment: Best to use modern join syntax

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that the EquipInstruct table is a many-to-many type "linking" table, I would code it this way:

```
select * from Instructor as i
join EquipInstruct as ei on i.[I-id] = ei.[I-id]
join Equipment as e on e.[E-id] = ei.[E-id]
```

This would display the alignment of equipment connected instructor.